# How to Switch out Windows 10 Home in S Mode

Tags: windows-10

Please let me know how to disable Windows 10 Home in S Mode?

Already I followed following steps:
Microsoft Store App > In the app, search for "switch out of s mode"

On the Switch out of S mode, selected Get button but it says unable to upgrade Try again.

Let me know, how to disable Windows 10 Home in S Mode?

Regards
John

Answer (score 1):

Try this procedure :

1. Go to Start -> Settings
2. Select Update & Security
3. Select Activation, and then select Go to Store.
4. Select the Get option.
5. Then hit Install when ready to proceed.

The process to switch out of S mode is a few seconds.
You do not need to restart the PC for it to take effect.

If this doesn't work, please supply more information about your device
and version of Windows.

It is possible that your device was sold to you cheaper because it came with
Window 10s, with S Mode already built-in,
so switching it off is counted as an upgrade to Windows 10 Home,
which may require payment, or is even flatly impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you install ALL the latest **Windows** & **Store** updates before trying to switch from S mode.
In my case, I got the "Unable to switch out of Windows 10 S mode" error message because I haven't updated Store (it may sound a little mind-bending, **but you update MS Store app from inside Store**).